# MATLAB How to vectorize these for loops?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I've searched a lot but didn't find any solution to my problem, could you please help me vectorizing (or just a way to make it way faster) these loops ?

```
% n is the size of C
h = 1/(n-1)
dt = 1e-6;
a = 1e-2;

F=zeros(n,n);
F2=zeros(n,n);
C2=zeros(n,n);


t = 0.0;

for iter=1:12000

    F2=F.^3-F;
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
             F2(i,j)=F2(i,j)-(C(ij(i-1),j)+C(ij(i+1),j)+C(i,ij(j-1))+C(i,ij(j+1))-4*C(i,j)).*(a.^2)./(h.^2);
        end
    end
    F=F2;
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
            C2(i,j)=C(i,j)+(F(ij(i-1),j)+F(ij(i+1),j)+F(i,ij(j-1))+F(i,ij(j+1))-4*F(i,j)).*dt./(h^2);
        end
    end
    C=C2;
    t = t + dt;


end

function i=ij(i) %Just to have a matrix as loop (the n+1 th cases are the 1 th and 0 the 0th are nth)
if i==0
    i=n;
    return 
elseif i==n+1
    i=1;
end 
return 
end
```

thanks a lot

EDIT: Found an answer, it was totally ridiculous and I was searching way too far

```
%n is still the size of C
h = 1/((n-1))
dt = 1e-6;
a = 1e-2;

F=zeros(n,n);
var1=(a^2)/(h^2); %to make a bit less calculus
var2=dt/(h^2); % the same


t = 0.0;

for iter=1:12000

    F=C.^3-C-var1*(C([n 1:n-1],1:n) + C([2:n 1], 1:n) + C(1:n, [n 1:n-1]) + C(1:n, [2:n 1]) - 4*C);
    C = C + var2*(F([n 1:n-1], 1:n) + F([2:n 1], 1:n) + F(1:n, [n 1:n-1]) + F(1:n,[2:n 1]) - 4*F);
    t = t + dt;

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer, it was totally ridiculous and I was searching way too far

```
%n is still the size of C
h = 1/((n-1))
dt = 1e-6;
a = 1e-2;

F=zeros(n,n);
var1=(a^2)/(h^2); %to make a bit less calculus
var2=dt/(h^2); % the same

prev = [n 1:n-1];
next = [2:n 1];

t = 0.0;

for iter=1:12000

    F = C.*C.*C - C - var1*(C(:,next)+C(:,prev)+C(next,:)+C(prev,:)-4*C);
    C = C + var2*(F(:,next)+F(:,prev)+F(next,:)+F(prev,:)-4*F);
    t = t + dt;

end
```

Comment: I think you can make it a little shorter yet by saying just `:` instead of `1:n`, when you're grabbing the whole row or column without shifting.

Comment: And give yourself the green checkmark (when you can).  My answer isn't as helpful with the `C.^3` in the formula.

Comment: Ok it's edited thanks and I can only accept my own answer in 2 days

Comment: Actually, I've got another question, I usually test it with a 128*128 random matrix but when I go over 130*130 , the final matrix is composed of NaN, it's not important but do you have an idea why it could be ?

Comment: Is it already NaN after the first iteration?  If not, how many iterations does it take?

Comment: I had to go to n=150 to see a fast decay, the whole matrix is zeros at the 6th iteration and then some + or - inf appears, then at the 14th, it's whole NaN

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the inner loop looks like a 2-dimensional circular convolution.  That's the same as multiplication in the FFT domain.  Subtraction is invariant across a linear operation such as FFT.

You'll want to use the `fft2` and `ifft2` functions.

Once you do that, I think you'll find that the repeated convolution can be eliminated by raising the convolution kernel (element-wise) to the power `iter`.  If that optimization is correct, I'm predicting a speedup of 5 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I finally found a really simple solution that even allows me to erase my ij function, it's just in 2 lines in the main for

Comment: @user1930360: I suppose you didn't understand my suggestion then.  My approach would get rid of your `ij` function and ALL the loops.

Comment: My first attempt to answer to you was to say that i didn't understand a thing you were saying ;) but then i found the answer so I changed it. But I really tried to understand and appreciated your help.

Comment: Looking again, because `F2=F.^3-F;` is nonlinear, you couldn't get rid of that or the outermost loop.

Comment: Finally found out you where totally right, your solution was much more efficient but I still don't understand it, even with a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace for example `C(ij(i-1),j)` by using `circshift(C,[1,0])` or `circshift(C,[1,0])` (i can't figure out witch one of two is correct)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I finally found a really simple solution that even allows me to erase my ij function, it's just in 2 lines in the main for